# How do I make a button change a certain value in my javascript application?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a application using JS and HTML and was wondering how to implement a button that will update a value with the parameters of three items to choose from.

Here was I got so far:

This is how the "value" is displayed in html -

```html
<div id="md" class="mdtxt">{mode}</div>
```

Using the following script to automatically update the value from default through js -

```html
<script>
document.getElementById("md").innerHTML = currentMode;
</script>
```

Here is the js side of things -

script.js with

```js
let currentMode = null;
```

(is nulled to demonstrate default)

config.js defines modes as

```js
config.zones = [
    {
        modeid: 1,
        modetag: "Mode #1",
    },
    {
        modeid: 2,
        modetag: "Mode #2",
    },
    {
        modeid: 3,
        modetag: "Mode #3",
    },
]
```

Hopefully I gave a good understanding, now I want my html button to be able to cycle through the modes and then wrap back around to the first one in a continuous cycle.

I have a html button element with a id so the element would be `id="btns1"`

I've tried to use some code from a previous project, as well as watch so youtube tutorials but nothing seems to be helping me understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to change the content of a `<div>` when you click a button, and to cycle through different options for that content (for example listed in the `config.zone` variable in your case), you can do something like this (to stay close to what you already have):

```html
<div id="md"></div>
<button onclick="selectMode()">Change Mode!</button>
    
<script>
    let config = Object // Ignore this, I need it because I don't know what your config variable is.
    config.zones = [
        {
            modeid: 1,
            modetag: "Mode #1",
        },
        {
            modeid: 2,
            modetag: "Mode #2",
        },
        {
            modeid: 3,
            modetag: "Mode #3",
        }
    ]
    
    let modeID = 1
    let currentMode = config.zones.filter((zone) => zone.modeid == modeID)[0].modetag
    document.getElementById("md").innerHTML = currentMode;
    function selectMode() {
        modeID = modeID < config.zones.length ? modeID + 1 : 1
        currentMode = config.zones.filter((zone) => zone.modeid == modeID)[0].modetag
        document.getElementById("md").innerHTML = currentMode;
    }
</script>
```

To create also different channels for each mode, you can create a property called `channels`, with a list of channels you want to cycle through for your mode.
The rest is similar to changing the mode.
For that purpose I changed the script a bit:

```html
<div id="md"></div>
<div id="ch"></div>
<button onclick="changeMode()">Change Mode!</button>
<button onclick="changeChannel()">Change Channel!</button>
    
<script>
    let config = Object // Ignore this, I need it because I don't know what your config variable is.
    config.zones = [
        {
            modeid: 1,
            modetag: "Mode #1",
            channels: [1,2,3,4],
        },
        {
            modeid: 2,
            modetag: "Mode #2",
            channels: [5,6,7,8],
        },
        {
            modeid: 3,
            modetag: "Mode #3",
            channels: [10,11],
        }
    ]
    
    let modeID = 1;
    let channelIndex = 0;
    document.getElementById("md").innerHTML = set('mode');
    document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML = set('channel');
    function changeMode() {
        modeID = modeID < config.zones.length ? modeID + 1 : 1;
        currentMode = set('mode');
        channelIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("md").innerHTML = set('mode');
        document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML = set('channel');
    }
    function changeChannel() {
        channelIndex = channelIndex < config.zones.filter((zone) => zone.modeid == modeID)[0].channels.length-1 ? channelIndex + 1 : 0
        document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML = set('channel');
    }
    function set(name='mode') {
        let mode = config.zones.filter((zone) => zone.modeid == modeID)[0]
        if (name == 'mode') {
            return mode.modetag
        } else if (name == 'channel') {
            return mode.channels[channelIndex]
        } else {
            console.log('Error! name needs to be either "mode" or "channel".');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Now that modes can be cycled/selected, is there a way to add “channels” so they can be cycled through as well. So for example I want channel 1-4 to be available only when modeID is equal to 1 and channel 6-8 available only when modeID is equal to 2 and etc?

Comment: I am not following well what you want. 
Are the "channel" supposed to be displayed anywhere? Also, for example when the modeID is equal to 1, which channel is going to be selected between 1-4?

Comment: Yes, the "channel" is displayed right below the mode as shown in the following picture. (I'm not the best a drawing lol) [Picture](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/555947468051841024/1156719730435035207/image.png) and the ID of the channel element is **ch**. And when modeID is 1 I want to be able to select channels 1-4 only.

Comment: There is another button to specifically change the channel, which is **btns2**

Comment: Alrighty, this is working, how would I Display a name connected to the channel rather than a plain number? Examples: [What I currently have](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/555947468051841024/1156741643488206930/image.png) vs [What I want it to be displayed as](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/555947468051841024/1156741883834408991/image.png) and this would be the [list of channels like above with added names](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/555947468051841024/1156742814684676156/image.png) The Unique name is defined as **name: "Specific Name"**

Comment: In this example I last picture, "SA Law Disp" would essentially be the "Unique Name". Sorry If I'm not giving enough information or mis-explaining.

Comment: Instead of numbers, you define the channels with whatever names you want to associate to them.